# What does "fields and methods are equivalent" mean?

Tags: scala, methods, field, uap

In the [Laziness](http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Functional%20programming-Laziness) section of 'Effective Scala', it says:

> Fields in scala are computed by need when val is prefixed with lazy. Because fields and methods are equivalent in Scala (lest the fields are private[this])

What does it mean by 'fields' and 'methods' being equivalent? Isn't it a rather strong statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it simply means that you can define an abstract `val` by a `def` and an abstract `def` by a `val`.

For example

```
trait Server {
  def port:Int
}
```

has an abstract function, namely `port`. You can for sure implement (or define or override) this with a `def`, like this

```
object DefaultServer extends Server {
  override def port: Int = 80
}
```

But in this case every access to `port` will cause a function application (or a method call) which is simply unnecessary. For this simple reason Scala gives us the possibility of implementing the abstract `def` with a value:

```
object DefaultServer extends Server {
  override val port: Int = 80
}
```

The same applies to abstract values. You can define abstract values with the same syntax:

```
trait Server {
  val port: Int
}
```

And you can override them with a `def`:

```
object DefaultServer extends Server {
  override def port: Int = 80
}
```

**Stability**

You may wonder what will happen if you override an abstract `val` with a `def` which gives you a different value each time you call it. Will you get the first computed value because the item is a `val` or you will get a different value each time you call it because the actual implementation is a `def`.

For example:

```
object DefaultServer extends Server {
  override def port: Int = scala.util.Random.nextInt()
}
```

Fortunately Scala compiler detects this and throws the following error:

```
error: overriding value a in trait Server of type Int;
method a needs to be a stable, immutable value
   override def port:Int = scala.util.Random.nextInt()
```

**Laziness**

When it comes to laziness this uniform behavior (treating fields and methods in the same way) is very useful.

First note that a `lazy` abstract value does not exist, i.e. you can not define an abstract `val` as `lazy`.

Implementing an abstract `def` by a `lazy val`, on the other hand, is perfectly legal and useful. The `lazy` value will be computed only on the first call and memoized (cached and used for future calls).

Comment: I always get the "method needs to be a stable, immutable value" error when I override a val with a def.

Comment: Are you sure it's not when you override a `val` with a `lazy val`?

Answer (score 1):

Fields and methods are equivalent due to [Uniform Access Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle):

> All services offered by a module should be available through a uniform notation, which does not betray whether they are implemented through storage or through computation

See more info about [how it's implemented](http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-nine-uniform-access/) in Scala.

P.S. UAP in Scala seems to be [not completely implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623074/why-its-impossible-to-override-var-with-def-in-scala)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason might be that, `lazy val` and `def` are computed before they are used (not when first defined).

The difference comes in as `lazy val` tries to avoid re-evaluations of an unchanging value, which has added cost of keeping the computed value in memory.