# Java constructor for my app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to Android development.
To create a tabbed Activity, I created three Java classes: 1) About; 2) Search; 3) List;

In my layout for Search I want to have a search bar, so I created an EditText (by drag and drop) and also a Button (by drag and drop).
In order to make my tabs work, in my Search.java I have the following code:

```
public class Search extends Fragment{


        //@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    }
```

Now in my Search.java class I also want to start working on code for my search bar, but in order to do that I think I need a constructor that starts like this like in a main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
```

But when I write code for it, it gives me these errors:

1) on `protected`: 'onCreate(Bundle) in 'com.example.alex.project.Search' crashes with 'onCreate(Bundle)' in 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment; attempting to assign weaker access privileges ('protected'); was 'public'
2)on `setContentView`: cannot resolve method 'setContentView(int)'

What can I do or what do I need to change to start writing Java code for search bar in 'onCreate(Bundle)' method?
Or do I need to do it somewhere else?

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You have the method signature wrong.</s> [You can't weaken the access privilege of an overridden method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510152/why-cant-we-assign-weaker-privilege-in-subclass/) Use

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

You can access your `EditText` in `OnViewCreated`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Parameter view is the inflated view you passed in onCreateView

    // Replace with your id
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that, then when I put code inside it, for example, when I try using stuff like `sTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sTxt);` (sTxt being ID of editText area from search.xml(by drag and drop)), on findViewById() it gives me this error : cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'

Comment: `setContentView`, `findViewById`, etc are methods of `Activity`. Your class is a `Fragment`.

Comment: Do I need to create `Activity` class for Search then?

Comment: How is the method signature wrong?? `onCreateView` is fine for Fragments. You can also use `rootView.findViewById` there

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention, I also need a button in there because it is part of a search bar I want to create. Now it tells me that button cannot be resolved. Also, I want user to not be able to press the button(search) if there is nothing in the search bar. So I also want to use `sTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {` and it tells me that TextWatcher cannot be resolved, also the same when I try to `myBtn.setEnabled`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding second issue, looks like you haven't defined `search` layout. You need to have a layout `search.xml` in your res/layout folder: read more here: [What is R.layout.search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955041/what-is-r-layout-search)

If you have it - than you should call `setContentView` method in your `MainActivity` class that extends `*Activity`, since `Fragment` class doen't have such method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, if I wasn't clear, but I do have `search.xml`, if that was what you meant.

Comment: Is the 2) issue still appears after fixing the 1) one?

Comment: Haven't managed to fix anything yet. If you mean `search.xml` I always had it. If I try changing `protected` to `public` onCreate(bundle), it doesn't give me the 1 error anyone, but 2 still remains.

Comment: I tried adding code(regarding search bar(edit text, buttons etc)) to my main activity, but then when I run it, emulator is not able to open the app, it says that it keep stopping and then that it cannot be opened.

Comment: You need to extend some `Activity` class with you `Search` , however. Refer to this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: I can't really extend my Search.java as it is already extended by Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I need a constructor that starts like this

That's not a constructor. Everything you asked about are methods.

> on protected: 'onCreate(Bundle) in 'com.example.alex.project.Search' clashes with 'onCreate(Bundle)' in 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Not sure about that, but all methods you mentioned should generally be `public`, not `protected`.

You should also un-comment `@Override`.

> What can I do/what do I need to change to start writing java code for search bar

You need to do something like this with what you have.

```
View rootView = ...

SearchBar search = (SearchBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
// edit searchbar

return rootView;
```

`onCreate` for an Activity is like `onCreateView`, and `setContentView` is essentially what `return rootView` does for a Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Write that where? Sorry, I don't really understand. Where does SearchBar come from? I have editText field and a button in my search.xml that I thought I should turn into a search bar, and I want to write code for it, for example, that button should be disabled until user puts text into text field part of my search bar.